# Github/ Bitbucket not showing correct commit / contribution history

Tags: git, graph, bitbucket, sourcetree

On Github, when I go to the graphs section for one of my recently completed projects, I get this image:

[image]

However, this is entirely inaccurate - when I go to SourceTree and look at the history, I can see I had far more than 19 commits.  Just looking at it now, I can see that I had around 50 commits.

What should I do to make GitHub accurately reflect these changes?

**Looking at the commits GitHub has registered, the first commit is from the last time I cloned the repository into my computer. How do I register the commits from the previous times I had the repository on my computer?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your ```username``` and ```email``` set in git?

Comment: Yeah, they are. That's how I imagine it registers the original 16 commits

Comment: maybe try to re add it by ```git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"``` and ```git config --global user.name "Your Name"```

Comment: Where would I add this in? I've been pushing it from IntelliJ straight into GitHub

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I'm running IntelliJ on Mac

Comment: just open ```terminal``` in directory where are stored your files which you use with git or ```cd``` there and apply commands which I send above.

Comment: Hah, that would make sense. I edited the question body to add more detail - it didn't register my commits from before the last time I cloned the repository. Any ideas?